# Determine resistor's value

Tags: resistors

Can you help me identify this resistor please? Is it 1.91 ohms resistor? In such case where would I find such resistor to replace this burned one?

[image: resistor]

Comment: Nice photo but this is close to impossible to answer from what you have given us. If those bands have been burned we have no idea what colour they started. Have you tried to measure the resistor? Where did it come from? Please read the guidelines on asking identification questions in the site tour under help.

Comment: The photo seems to be missing some colour information. Edit your question to list the colours from left to right. You would find resistors at any electronic component supplier. Shopping questions get closed very quickly so don't ask!

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell, as the heat from the failure has changed the colours. It's likely 39 something, as that's the only E12 value which would match (68 is possible but less likely).

Your best bet is to sketch the surrounding circuits and post a picture and we may be able to infer what the value should have been.

Comment: There are 5 rings, so I think it should a E96-value resistor…